# Can an objective criticism of somebodies work, which might hurt feelings, violate 'Right Speech' precept?

Tags: personal-practice, right-speech

If we write or verbally express an objective criticism of someone's work, for e.g. if I write a bad(but honest) review of my friends movie, or if I tell my friend that I don't like her cooking (instead of lying to keep her mind), or if I tell an honest truth to someone about something related to him/her, but if in all these situations the words will cause hurtful feelings to the other, will that constitute 'wrong speech' adding up to bad karma or not?

**Note:** I will be telling truth in all situations as perceived by me. And the intention here is not to do harm but just to express my feelings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MN58 [Abhaya Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.058.than.html):

> (1) In the case of words that the Tathagata knows to be unfactual/untrue, unbeneficial, and unendearing/disagreeable [i.e. painful - AV]  to others -- he does not say them.
>
> (2) In the case of words that the Tathagata knows to be factual/true but
>   unbeneficial and unendearing/disagreeable to others -- he does not say
>   them.
>
> (3) In the case of words that the Tathagata knows to be factual/true and
>   beneficial, but *unendearing/disagreeable to others* -- **he has a sense
>   of the proper time for saying them.**
>
> (4) In the case of words that the Tathagata knows to be unfactual/untrue, unbeneficial, and yet endearing/agreeable to others -- he does not
>   say them.
>
> (5) In the case of words that the Tathagata knows to be factual/true,
>   unbeneficial, and endearing/agreeable to others -- he does not say
>   them.
>
> (6) In the case of words that the Tathagata knows to be factual/true, and
>   beneficial, and endearing/agreeable to others -- he has a sense of the
>   proper time for saying them. Why is that? Because the Tathagata has
>   sympathy for living beings."

Also:

> It's as if a man were shot with an arrow thickly smeared with poison. As a result of being shot with the arrow, he would feel fierce, sharp, racking pains. His friends & companions, kinsmen & relatives would provide him with a surgeon. The surgeon would cut around the opening of the wound with a knife. **As a result of the surgeon's cutting around the opening of the wound with a knife, the man would feel fierce, sharp, racking pains**. The surgeon would probe for the arrow with a probe. As a result of the surgeon's probing for the arrow with a probe, the man would feel fierce, sharp, racking pains. The surgeon would then pull out the arrow. **As a result of the surgeon's pulling out the arrow, the man would feel fierce, sharp, racking pains**. The surgeon would then apply a burning medicine to the mouth of the wound. **As a result of the surgeon's applying a burning medicine to the mouth of the wound, the man would feel fierce, sharp, racking pains**. But then at a later time, when the wound had healed and was covered with skin, he would be well & happy, free, master of himself, able to go wherever he liked. The thought would occur to him, "Before, I was shot with an arrow thickly smeared with poison. As a result of being shot with the arrow, I felt fierce, sharp, racking pains. My friends & companions, kinsmen & relatives provided me with a surgeon... The surgeon cut around the opening of the wound with a knife... probed for the arrow with a probe... pulled out the arrow... applied a burning medicine to the mouth of the wound. As a result of his applying a burning medicine to the mouth of the wound, I felt fierce, sharp, racking pains. But now that the wound is healed and covered with skin, I am well & happy, free, master of myself, able to go wherever I like."

Can an objective criticism of somebodies work, which might hurt feelings, violate 'Right Speech' precept? -- Yes, it can: 1) if it is not beneficial; 2) if it is not said at the proper time.

Comment: Good citation! Interesting how the category of untrue/unfactual, but beneficial was left out altogether.

Comment: That would constitute lying isn't it! So would be wrong speech that ways.

Comment: @FriedrickNietzsche Perhaps the comment on "unfactual but beneficial" was an allusion to [upaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upaya#Parable_of_the_burning_house).

Answer (score 4):

> Potaliya, four kinds of people exist and can be found in the world. 
>   What four kinds?  The four kinds are:
>
> Some people blame those who should be blamed, according to the truth,
>   at the proper time, but do not praise those who should be praised,
>   according to the truth, at the proper time.
>
> Some people praise those who should be praised, according to the
>   truth, at the proper time, but do not blame those who should be
>   blamed, according to the truth, at the proper time.
>
> Some people do not blame those who should be blamed, according to the
>   truth, at the proper time, and do not praise those who should be
>   praised, according to the truth, at the proper time.
>
> Some people blame those who should be blamed, according to the truth,
>   at the proper time, and praise those who should be praised, according
>   to the truth, at the proper time.
>
> Potaliya, these four kinds of people exist and can be found in the
>   world.  Of these four kinds of people, that kind should be the most
>   fair and right, the most refined, to you?
>
> Venerable Lord Gotama, of all those four kinds of people, the kind of
>   person who does not blame those who should be blamed, according to the
>   truth, at the proper time, and does not praise those who should be
>   praised, according to the truth, at the proper time; is the kind of
>   person who is the most beautiful and refined to me.  What is the
>   reason for this?  Because this is fair and right with upekkha
>   (equanimity).
>
> Potaliya, of all those four kinds of people, whichever kind of person
>   blames those who should be blamed, according to the truth, at the
>   proper time, and praises those who should be praised, according to the
>   truth, at the proper time; this kind of person is the most beautiful
>   and refined of these four kinds of people.  What is the reason for
>   this?  It is fair and right because such a one knows the right time in
>   those circumstances.
>
> [AN 4.100](https://suttacentral.net/an4.100/en/sujato)

Answer (score 0):

most important thing is what is the purpose of saying or doing something. If you are doing something without defilement then it is OK. (ex. anger) also it should give a right benefit for both side.

Answer (score 0):

" And the intention here is not to do harm but just to express my feelings " you already answered your question, if your intention is not harm, that it. You do nothing wrong then. If someone is intentionally say something to hurt someone that will be add bad karma.